# SVG losing its curvature when in a Container

Tags: flutter

I have an svg as a child in a container. I'm using this [package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_svg) . The svg is curved at one side but it loses this curvature when rendered.

```
Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30,right: 30,bottom: 10),
              child: ClipRRect(
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/img/mask_purple_energizer.svg',height: 200,width: 1000,),
                    color: Theme.of(context).cardColor),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              ),
            ),
```

Here is the gist of the svg file:

https://gist.github.com/horgag1/66ef8ab683f26b9c19a318769a2cf3e9

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with a `Stack` instead of a `Container`? And what if you resize the SVG width to 100, for example, can you give it a try? I'm asking you this, so I can further explain you what's happening.

Comment: The width never changes, even when I adjust the width property. I can't really use a stack. The svg should feel part of the container and not above it

Comment: Can you edit your question with the SVG that you are using so I can provide you with a full answer?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think clip rects are supported by the SVG plugin you're using, or at least not how they are in your SVG. The right-side corners aren't being cropped properly either, but you can't tell that because the ClipRRect takes care of it.

If the SVG editor you're using supports it, you may be able to apply the clip to each shape instead of having it separate. Otherwise, your options are to either raise a bug or add clipping to the plugin, or to use a [ClipPath widget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ClipPath-class.html) and manually define the clipping path (or copy it out of the svg).